# Erlang node connection timeout

Tags: networking, erlang

I have a bunch of erlang nodes running on a single machine, and they are all connected in a network. Sometimes the machine our application is on will be under extremely heavy load for several minutes. Often, after things return to normal, my erlang nodes think that they were disconnected, and I have to manually call `net_adm:ping` on each one of them to get them to re-connect to the network.

Any ideas on how I can avoid this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the value of `net_ticktime` [kernel configuration option](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html) so nodes will be pinged more infrequently. See also [net_kernel:set_net_ticktime](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#set_net_ticktime-1). Note, however, that all communicating nodes should have the same `net_ticktime` value specified.